# Simple property not found

Tags: jsp, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am using aui in jsp page to implement portlet following is the code in which error occurs jodd.bean.BeanException simple property not found:cMessage invalid property...

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text href="<%= rowURL %>"
        name="cMessage" property="cMessage" />
```

using above code retrieving data from databse displaying null with jodd.bean.BeanException and replacing property attribute with value="<%=currentCourse.getCMessage()%>" data is retrieved from db but still the error jodd.bean.BeanException occurs.how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the model used in the search container in order to check the properties you have got available?.

Maybe you're using a property that don't exist in the model, and this is raising the exception.

Hope it helps